# MYSQL Inner Join Get Multiple Names From IDs

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a query using INNER JOIN in MYSQL and I can't get it working.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

***Please note that these are not the tables I am working on. I made two simple tables to show what I am trying to achieve.***

Here is an image of the table index relation:
http://oi62.tinypic.com/2ez5k3p.jpg

I want to get **"sender"** and **"receiver"** names from **tb_people** and combine them as this:

**TABLE EXAMPLE**

**| sender | receiver |**

**| JOHN | MARY |**

Here is one of the queries I tried and failed

```
SELECT
    tb_people.p_name AS sender,
    tb_people.p_name AS receiver
FROM
    tb_people
INNER JOIN 
    tb_mail
ON (tb_people.id = tb_mail.sender_id)
AND (tb_people.id = tb_mail.receiver_id)
```

Can you please advise me on how to fix this query?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two `join`s and table aliases:

```
SELECT s.p_name AS sender, r.p_name AS receiver
FROM tb_mail m INNER JOIN
     tb_people r
     ON r.id = m.sender_id INNER JOIN
     tb_people s
     ON s.id = m.receiver_id;
```

If you think about your `on` condition:

```
ON (tb_people.id = tb_mail.sender_id) AND
   (tb_people.id = tb_mail.reciever_id)
```

You'll realize that the condition is only true when the sender and receiver is the same person.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works like a charm. This has been bugging me all day long and now it works.
Yes like you said with 'AND' I was forcing the query to bring the entries that share an ID.

Answer (score 0):

a WHERE IN is easier! Have a look at it:

```
SELECT
    tb_people.p_name AS sender,
    tb_people.p_name AS receiver
FROM
    tb_people
WHERE tb_people.id IN (
    SELECT tb_mail.sender_id
    FROM tb_mail
)
```

This should get the sender and receiver from every mail, which is stored in the database.